# Compilation Error Due to Incompatibility Between Prettier v3 and @vue/eslint-config-prettier v7.x

Tags: vuejs2, eslint, vue-cli, prettier, eslintrc

Updating prettier to version 3 has lead to the following error during the compilation:

```
> 1 | [object Promise]
|         ^
2 | export { render, staticRenderFns }
at constructor (/xxx/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:348:19)
at JSXParserMixin.raise (/xxx/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3202:19)
at JSXParserMixin.unexpected (/xxx/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3232:16)
at JSXParserMixin.expect (/xxx/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3569:28)
at JSXParserMixin.parseExprList (/xxx/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11944:14)
at JSXParserMixin.parseArrayLike (/xxx/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11853:26)
at JSXParserMixin.parseExprAtom (/xxx/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11122:23)
at JSXParserMixin.parseExprAtom (/xxx/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:6916:20)
at JSXParserMixin.parseExprSubscripts (/xxx/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10839:23)
.
.
.
at async.call.result.err.err (/xxx/node_modules/gensync/index.js:223:11)
@ ./src/components/component.vue?vue&type=template&id=b5448588& 1:0-363 1:0-363
@ ./src/components/component.vue 1:0-95 9:2-8 10:2-17 29:79-34:5 31:16-22 32:25-40 29:4-34:6
@ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/@vue/vue-loader-v15/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./src/components/component.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 1:0-65 4:22-38
@ ./src/components/component.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 1:0-240 1:256-259 1:261-498 1:261-498
@ ./src/components/component.vue 2:0-68 3:0-63 3:0-63 9:2-8
@ ./src/main.js 11:0-65 27:17-33
```

This was caused by the incompatibility of `@vue/eslint-config-prettier` v7.x with prettier v3.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
updating `@vue/eslint-config-prettier` to v8.